# One-click Registration - am I missing something here?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, user-registration

I'm trying to implement a 'one-click' Facebook registration process on my site. I'm getting extremely wound up because on other sites with what I want, they just have a 'Register with FB' button which they click and they're instantly given an account.

But if I go to the FB documentation for Registration its talking about displaying an entire form in an iframe with values prefilled (which none of the other websites seem to need?).

I have a FB Login button, which gave me a popup dialog asking to auth permissions and then I added a registration-url to send them to my registration page if they don't have an account (not sure how FB knows this? I guess it means not authorised?). So then how do I authorise the app with one click on the registration page?

All I want to do is initiate a request on my server to make the registration using the FB user's email and user_id. I can store these in MySQL.

Click Register > Authorise app. Whenever you want to log into the system you just click Login (saving you entering an email and password for registering and logging in).

Am I missing something? I can't seem to see this anywhere?

I can't understand what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

use php sdk to access the users info after the dialog.  something like below, but probally want to check database for exists.

```
$email=$user_profile[email];
$uid=$user_profile[id];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mydatabase (`id`, `email`) VALUES (\''.$uid.'\', \''.$email.'\');';
$insert=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error! in Insert '.$uid.' SQL');
```